# EF Navigation Property with null foreign key

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

I'm attempting to use navigation properties for the first time in lieu of doing joins.  I cannot get a situation to work where it would normally be done with a left outer join.  In the following example, I'm only getting results back where the foreign key is non-null.  I need all results back.  What am I missing?

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID {get;set;}

    public String Name {get;set;}
}

public class Shipment
{
    [Key]
    public int ShipmentID {get;set;}

    public int? SignedForByID {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("SignedForByID")]
    public virtual User SignedForBy{get;set;}
}
```

navigation property mapping:

```
 Shipment.HasOptional(x=> x.SignedForBy).WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(y=> y.SignedForByID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

query:

```
var data = (from s in context.Set<Shipment>()
            select new {
                    ShipmentID = s.ShipmentID,
                    SignedForBy = s.SignedForBy
                        });
```

Comment: Is the context variable a DbContext? Can you show the implementation of the `Shipments` method you are calling?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I edit the post to clarify this.  It's just a DbSet

Comment: I'm stumped then, I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: The problem seems to be related with the mapping of the navigation property itself and not the value of the foreign key.  I tried doing the left outer join with the models as above and it still failed to work.  However, if I remove the navigation property it works as expected.

Comment: I've just realized that in your mapping you reference a property on the Shipment class called User but there is no property shown in your models?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  My actual code is much larger, this was just a small example of what i'm doing and I mis-typed it.  I'll update the post with the correction.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove ForeignKey attribute from the model as you define the relation in the mapping code. It worked for me in the similar situation.

Comment: I need the foreign key attribute to build the mapping.  the mappings are done dynamically in a helper class that uses the attributes to generate the fluent api for the mappings.

Comment: I tested your code, and the query you have gets all shipments even the ones that are signed by no user.

Comment: Yeah just to clarify, I also couldn't reproduce. I tested using EF6

Comment: Is the helper class that generates the fluent api mapping something that you wrote? It looks like you are defining the same relationship twice. Once using data annotations and again using fluent api. Something seems fishy there.

Comment: I found the problem!  I'm an idiot.  It seems that the mapping helper had a shaky if statement that would sometimes map the navigation parameters with the .HasRequire() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not shown in this example.  The mappings are generated by a helper class.  In some cases, the helper class incorrectly mapped the navigation properties with the .HasRequired() method instead of the .HasOptional(). Correcting the mapping class has fixed the issue.